# SignalR wpf server and ASP.NET MVC issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wpf, signalr, signalr-hub

I have in WPF SignalR server

```
public partial class MainWindow
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Closing += (s, e) => ViewModelLocator.Cleanup();
        StartOptions options = new StartOptions();

        options.Urls.Add("http://localhost:8080");
        using (WebApp.Start(options))
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Hub.cs

```
[HubName("clientPushHub")]
public class TestHub : Hub
{
    public string GetServerTime()
    {
        return DateTime.UtcNow.ToString();
    }

    public void Heartbeat()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hub Heartbeat\n");
        Clients.All.heartbeat();
    }

    public Task JoinGroup(string groupId)
    {
        return Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, groupId);
    }

    public void addHit(string pageId)
    {

    }
    public Task LeaveGroup(string groupId)
    {
        return Groups.Remove(Context.ConnectionId, groupId);
    }

    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        return (base.OnConnected());
    }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        PerformanceEngine performanceEngine = new PerformanceEngine(1000);
        Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => await performanceEngine.OnPerformanceMonitor());
        // map SignalR urls
        app.Map("/signalr", map =>
        {
            map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);

            var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration
            {
                EnableDetailedErrors = true
            };
            map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
        }
        );
    }
}
```

And in my ASP.NET MVC client I have
Index.cshtml

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/app.js"></script>

<body ng-app="signalRIntegrationApp">
    <div ng-controller="ServerTimeController">
        <div>
            <h3>Time from server (being pushed every 5 seconds):</h3>
            <h4>{{currentServerTime}}</h4>
        </div>

        </div>
</body>
```

and in app.js

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module("signalRIntegrationApp", []);
    app.service('signalRSvc', function ($rootScope) {
        var proxy = null;

        var initialize = function () {
            var connection = $.hubConnection("http://localhost:8080");
            proxy = connection.createHubProxy('clientPushHub');

            connection.start(function () {
                proxy.addHit();
            });

            proxy.on('serverTime', function (data) {
                    $rootScope.$emit('serverTime', data);
            });
        }

        return {
            initialize: initialize
        };
    });

    app.controller('ServerTimeController', ["$scope", 'signalRSvc', function($scope, signalRSvc) {
        var vm = this;

        $scope.$on("serverTime", function (e, data) {
            $scope.$apply(function () {
                vm.currentServerTime = data;
            });
        }); 
        signalRSvc.initialize();
    }]);
})()
```

When I start the client in Firefox I get the error on
[image: error]

The client is on http://localhost:8081 on IIS Express

**Update:**
Error during negotiation request

Comment: what is the error (HTTP status code)?

Comment: @Pawel Error during negotiation request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this part of code

```
 using (WebApp.Start(options))
 {
 }
```

You create and then immediately dispose server object. It means that you shut down server immediately after creation.

You should store reference to that object and call dispose when needed. Or just store object and let OS handle resource cleanup when process exits.

[Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.hosting.webapp.start(v=vs.113).aspx#Anchor_2)

Relevant part:

> Return Value
>
> Type: System.IDisposable
>
> An IDisposible instance that can be called to shut down the web app.